# How to check for a pre requisite and then install it in WiX?

Tags: wix, .net-4.8

I am creating an installer. I have a setup project for the same along with a bootstrapper project which consists of all my pre requisites. I would like to check if the .NETFramework 4.8 is installed in the machine, and only if the version 4.8 is not installed, I would like the installer to install the same. In order to achieve this I am making use of the NetFxExtension in my bootstrapper project.

After following some sources online, this is what I tried doing but it does not work.

```
<Fragment>
<PropertyRef Id="NetFx48Redist"/>
<Condition Message="Please install the .NET Framework 4.8 and run this installer again.">
<![CDATA[Installed OR NETFRAMEWORK48]]>
</Condition>
</Fragment>
```

Answer (score 0):

`WixNetFxExtension` includes package groups you can reference in your bundle's `Chain` element. .NET Framework v4.8 is supported on WiX v3.14 and v4. Here's a sample: https://wixtoolset.org/docs/v3/howtos/redistributables_and_install_checks/install_dotnet/